# Selecting multiple rows from a table and applying a function on a button click

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm trying to select multiple rows from a table using a check box for each row, and then applying a function to it when a button is clicked, I can't seem to find a way to select the rows with the check boxes checked and process them via an AJAX call.

Here is the PHP code that generates the table:

```
            echo '<table cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="viewData" id="approveTransfersTbl"> ';
            echo '<thead> ';
            echo '  <tr> ';
            echo '      <th>Transfer Type</th> ';       
            echo '      <th>Officer ID</th> ';      
            echo '      <th>Officer Name</th> ';        
            echo '      <th>Status</th> ';      
            echo '      <th>Req Date</th> ';    
            echo '      <th>From</th> ';
            echo '      <th>To</th> ';
            echo '      <th>Reason</th> ';
            //echo '        <th>More Info</th>';
            echo '      <th>Select</th>';
            echo '  </tr> ';
            echo '</thead> ';
            echo '<tbody> ';
                foreach($rows as $row){ 
                    echo '  <tr> ';
                    echo '<td>'.$row['transfer_type'].'</td> ';
                    echo '<td>'.$row['officer_Id'].'</td> ';
                    echo '<td>'.$row['name_with_Initials'].'</td> ';
                    echo '<td>'.$row['status_'].'</td> ';
                    echo '<td>'.$row['date_Requested'].'</td> ';
                    echo '<td>'.$row['frmprison_Name'].'</td> ';
                    echo '<td>'.$row['prison_Name'].'</td> ';
                    echo '<td>'.$row['Reason'].'</td> ';
                    echo "<td><input class='tblrowChkBox' id='tblrowChkBox".$row['transfer_Log_Id']."' type='checkbox' /></td>";

                    echo '  </tr> ';
                }   
                echo '</tbody> ';   
                echo '</table> ';  

                echo '</br></br>  ';    
                echo '<div style="width:320px; margin:auto;">';
                echo "<input type='button' class='button' id='btnapprove' name='btnapprove' value='Approve'' />";   
                echo "<input type='button' class='button' id='btnunchk' name='btnunchk' value='Un Check'/>";
                echo '</div>';
        }
```

Comment: what function you want to append? and can you please share a jsfiddle link?

Comment: i was thinking of submitting an array of all the checkbox values that are selected (i have to all the value attribute as value='".$row['transfer_Log_Id']."') to a php form via ajax when the button #btnapprove is clicked and update the database for each array value,

Comment: here is the jfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/reqz6emn/  i did not add the ajax call or the php code

Comment: please check the answer posted by me and check DEMO link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get list of value of checked checkbox using below code -

You need to modify below line and put value of checkbox equal to rowid

```
echo "<td><input class='tblrowChkBox' 
                 id='tblrowChkBox".$row['transfer_Log_Id']."' 
                 type='checkbox' 
                 value='".$row['transfer_Log_Id']."'/></td>";
```

Use below script to bind click event to button and get checkbox valur array

```
$(document).on("click",'#btnapprove',function(){
    var selectedCheckboxes = $('input[class="tblrowChkBox"]:checked').map(function(){

      return $(this).val();
    }).get();

    alert(selectedCheckboxes);
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/reqz6emn/8/)**

Comment: yup now i just have to send that array via an ajax call and execute a query for each value to update the database! - thanks again

Comment: I thought my answer helped you

Answer (score 0):

user common group name for check-boxs(ex: name = 'checkGroup') & following code could help you to get the row list

```
  var $rowList = $('[name=checkGroup]:checked').map(function(){
                   return $(this).parent().parent();
                 })
```

Comment: I think you can return only `$(this).val();` instead of parent's parent

Comment: @AmjadNaz, do you want array of `tr` or array of selected checkbox?

Comment: im thinking an array of chekboxes would be easier since i want their values only, can i get that by return $(this) for the above piece of code